# How to get the directory tree of files I have read premission on

Tags: permissions, directory

I want to get the directory tree of all the files in a server to which I have read permission. how can I do this!?

Comment: `find / -perm +r`

Comment: and how to exclude the permission denied errors?

Comment: Add a error redirect `find / -perm +r 2>/dev/null`

Comment: you may also want to try `sudo` before the cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods come to mind, `find` and `tree`. Of the two I think `tree` fits your question better.

**Find**
    `find` has the advantage that it is a basic package likely to be found in any linux distro. One disadvantage is that it will not generate a tree view. Nor will `grep`ing it for errors be easy. Instead add appropriate `-perm` tests. The following example will find all directories in `/` with user, group, and other read permission and send standard error to `/dev/null`

```
find / -type d -perm /u=r -perm /g=r -perm /o=r 2>/dev/null
```

**Tree**
   While `tree` may not be installed by default it is in the repos. It does create a tree view.  If the user running `tree` does not have read permission a simple `grep -v error` will remove the directory from the output. However removing the errors will potentially leave extraneous formating.  `-d` List directories only. `-p` Print the file type and permissions for each file (as per ls -l). `grep -v` prints lines not matching the pattern, `error`.

```
tree -d -p / | grep -v error
```